# Group By with Where clause in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I got some difference in the results when using a `DateTime` column in `groupby`. Can someone explain why?

Query:

```
Select Name, Source, Description, CreatedDate
   From testTable
   Where Source like '%Validating err%' 
   And CreatedDate >='2016-12-01'
   Group By Name , Source, Description, CreatedDate
```

**Result :** 15 rows

The above query return me some 15 results. But when i remove the `CreatedDate` column from `groupby` clause it returns only 4 results.

Query:

```
Select Name, Source, Description
   From testTable
   Where Source like '%Validating err%' 
   And CreatedDate >='2016-12-01'
   Group By Name , Source, Description
```

**Result :** 4 rows

Comment: You are filtering date with `>=` not with `=` so It is obvious. Plus your second query also has `CreatedDate` which I think is a typo

Comment: @Prdp Shouldn't these queries not even run in SQL Server? (maybe in MySQL).

Comment: now both query should give you the same no of records

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I think it is typo.. OP is saying queries are returning records

Comment: @all : OOPS, updated now and that was a typo.

Comment: @John - Did you see my first comment

Comment: @Squirrel : No, its not

Comment: @John `Group by` is same in both the queries fix it

Comment: @Prdp But what the group by has to do with that?

Comment: There is nothing at all surprising about this.  There are 4 unique groups made up of name, source, description.  When you add the date column, this creates more combinations, and hence more groups.

Comment: @John - if you expect both the queries to result same number of records just change the `>=` to `=` else as mentioned by @tim in previous comment it is obvious you removed the date from group by now group is smaller

Answer (score 4):

I am adding this answer just for the benefit of @John so he can visually understand why his two result sets have differing numbers of records.

Imagine a table called `shirts`, which has only two columns, `size` and `color`.  Here is some sample data:

```
size | color
S    | red
S    | green
S    | blue
M    | red
M    | green
M    | blue
L    | red
L    | green
L    | blue
```

In other words, there are three sizes of shirts, and each size has three possible colors.

Now, if you execute the following query:

```
SELECT size
FROM shirts
GROUP BY size
```

you will get three records back, containing only the three sizes.  However, if you do the following:

```
SELECT size, color
FROM shirts
GROUP BY size, color
```

Then you would get back *nine* records, or groups.  All that is happening here is that the addition of another column creates new possible group combinations, and hence more groups.  And the same concept applies to what you are seeing in your two queries.